Why does FCM Stops working for specific phones?
We have thousands of users.  For a small number of users FCM push stops working.  If they sign into the app on another Android phone then it works for them.  It seems like the issue is tied to the specific phone.  FCM messages to that user on that phone are not delivered. Uninstalling/reinstalling on the trouble phone doesn't resolve the problem.  This seems very strange so I am asking if anyone has seen similiar behavior. Sending the user a new phone (enterprise) is the current solution.

Some manufacturers aggressively kill services that can stop normal functionality in the name of better battery life and that could be the issue
